# Wordpress advanced excerpt - use image in 'read more' link, using get bloginfo

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output a custom image in my excerpt 'read more' links.

Like so...

[image]

I am using the advanced exceprt plugin because it so much customizable for my needs.

This is how I've tried to output the excerpt with the image in the readmore link...

```
<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=120&use_words=0&no_custom=0&ellipsis=%26hellip;&read_more=read more <img src"' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '"/images/readmore-arrow.png" alt="" />&add_link=1'); ?>
```

But weirdly it outputs this readmore link...

[image]

I seems to break up the URL of the image location and output it like this...

```
<img alt="" readmore-arrow.png"="" images="" my-theme-name"="" themes="" wp-content="" wp="" mywebsitename.co.uk="" src"http:="">
```

Can any one help me fix this?

Thanks

---

Working code...

```
<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=120&use_words=0&no_custom=0&ellipsis=%26hellip;&rea‌​d_more=read more <img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/readmore-arrow.png" alt="" />&add_link=1'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will fix it for you as i've not used that plugin, but you're missing an `=` for the `src` attribute. I've added it in here:

```
<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=120&use_words=0&no_custom=0&ellipsis=%26hellip;&read_more=read more <img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '"/images/readmore-arrow.png" alt="" />&add_link=1'); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, I completely messed it up. I even put an extra speech mark after the get_bloginfo php. Thank you! `<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=120&use_words=0&no_custom=0&ellipsis=%26hellip;&read_more=read more <img src="' . get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/images/readmore-arrow.png" alt="" />&add_link=1'); ?>`